# Xcode Instruments

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-management, xcode-instruments

Iam trying to profile my app and want to check for memory leaks. Iam planing to use Xcode instruments.Any one suggest good tutorial to start with Xcode Instruments. Please suggest any alternatives.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is list of tutorial, some of them text document and videos

**Apple WWDC video tutorial about instrument**

1. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/418/
2. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/410/

**Official Apple Instrument document**

1. https://help.apple.com/instruments/mac/current/

**this is old Apple WWDC instrument tutorial video but worth to watch for good start**

1. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/310/

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

**Some others nice blogs you can refer:**

1. https://www.raywenderlich.com/397-instruments-tutorial-with-swift-getting-started
2. https://medium.com/@kazmiekr/what-every-ios-developer-should-be-doing-with-instruments-d1661eeaf64f
3. https://www.lynda.com/iOS-SDK-tutorials/Improving-iOS-performance-Xcode-Instruments/452088-2.html
4. http://www.spotlessicode.com/blog/posts/instruments-tutorial-part-1-profiling-templates-deferred-mode-launch-instruments